# Double-click and Shift+arrowkey selects multiple elements in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When you doubleclick `there` in what Chrome displays based on the following code or place the cursor left of `H` and press `CTRL + right arrow key`, the selection extends to all the text.

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Hi<strong>1</strong>there<span>2</span>you</div>
```

However it should only select `there` in the first and only `Hi` in the second case.

Can this behavior be corrected with CSS only? Or worst case with JavaScript? Note: It's not possible to add new symbols to the editable text area.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7o6ykLt0/19/

Desired outcome when double-clicking `there`:

[image: desired outcome]

Actual outcome:

[image: actual outcome]

Comment: It's not seeing more than one word there. You can see that by adding some CSS: `div { word-spacing: 2rem; }`. That should put a bunch of space between each word but in your example, everything is together. You would need to add something that indicates a word boundary, like a space, between the "words" as you see them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was hoping there was a way to make the behavior use <tags> to separate somehow without modifying the content. (updated question to reflect).

Answer (score 1):

Following Heretic Monkey's advice, you can insert a `&ZeroWidthSpace;` between your words:

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Hi&ZeroWidthSpace;<strong>1</strong>&ZeroWidthSpace;there&ZeroWidthSpace;<span>2</span>&ZeroWidthSpace;you</div>
```

You can also insert these characters dynamically:

```js
for (var node of document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").childNodes)
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    node.nodeValue = "\u200b" + node.nodeValue + "\u200b";
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Hi<strong>1</strong>there<span>2</span>you</div>
```

Comment: I can't actually add content to the editable text area. When I mentioned "HTML" as a solution, I was thinking of some magic property treatTagsAsWordBoundaries="true" or something. I updated the question. However, yeah, this is the perfect solution if adding characters is possible.

Comment: If you want to influence the behavior of the HTML page, you must somehow be able to change the page. Can you perhaps change the content dynamically, as in my augmented answer?